# ag-grid tooltip with hyperlink

Tags: javascript, html, css, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am using ag-grid. I want to implement a tooltip and the tooltip content will have hyperlinks in it. Is it possible to achieve this, as per my understanding if a user moves the mouse the tooltip will disappear and won't be able to click on the link?